# Pre-release versioning of python modules on github

Tags: python, github, versioning, release

I would like to put a version number in a Python module on github.  I would like the only commits that have an 'official' release version to be the commits tagged and included in a release.  For other commits, I'd like to use some version string that, if somebody makes a build from it, clearly indicates it is not a release build.  I will only change the version string when making release commits, and in a commit immediately following each release commit.

What is a suitable pre-release version format that will be widely understood?

I see both [PEP-440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) and the ["semantic versioning"](http://semver.org/) specification, but it's not immediately clear to me what to use for this purpose.

In particular, PEP-440 suggests pre-release versions like `0.1.2b1`.  That seems not to fulfil my criteria well because to me, it suggests that I built a `0.1.2b1` release, but I do not plan to make any such built pre-releases: I will only release `0.1.1`, `0.1.2`, `0.1.3`, etc, and intermediate versions will only be on github or built by other people.

Comment: Most projects don't bother with this, it is not worth the hassle. You just increment the release number each time right after you create a release, so that the development version is tagged as the next version.

Comment: What hassle is that?  I plan to use a script to release.

Comment: You'd have to plug in a version number during development, put in the right version number when you are about to release, tag, then switch back to a development version again.  A right pain.

Comment: The release script will do that for me.

Comment: Why don't you have a separate releasing branch, so it's unambiguous which revisions are considered released?

Comment: With SVN there was a sequential number you could use for that, but with git and other distributed systems there is no longer such a number. So you have to create you own, and this is as a pain in the backside that is just not worth it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so the scheme would be to call it say '0.1.2-dev', so no need for a sequential number, or any number in the '-dev' part.  Really here I'm asking for people to speak up where they have seen such conventions in use, not asking how to avoid any pain -- that's because I haven't encountered any!  If you personally haven't come across such a convention, there's probably no need to help out on this question I think...

Comment: @CroadLangshan: so my 20 years of experience accumulating to *nope, I don't bother anymore, it is not worth the pain* is of no value to you? Sometimes the answer really is *don't do that*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe A branch is fine but it doesn't help people who are not looking git but at `somemodule.__version__` from an installed package (and when I think about my own coding activities I do that more often than looking at git).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I certainly wouldn't say your 20 years of experience is of no value, but TBH I'm not really sure how to respond helpfully to a blunt "I'm right" statement.

Comment: @CroadLangshan: I commented, not answered, because it is my opinion. I never said that my opinion on this was *right*; you were the one being blunt here with the suggestion I don't help out! I have come across such conventions, but when using SVN, and in transitioning to Git and Mercurial I found that the pain isn't worth it, and OSS projects I worked with have dropped the notion altogether. Take that for what you will.

Comment: I meant blunt as in "unqualified by argument, mere argument from authority", but I apologize for being blunt in the other sense.